# What is the benefit of extending an interface AGAIN which is already extended by its parent?

Tags: java, android, interface

Say, I have below code:

```
interface IAAA {
    void aaa();
}

interface IBBB extends IAAA {
    void bbb();
}

class MyClass implements IAAA, IBBB {
    public void bbb() { }
    public void aaa() { }
}
```

Is there any benefit of implementing `IAAA` in `MyClass`?
As you can see, `IAAA` is already extended by `IBBB` and `MyClass` is implementing both `IAAA` and `IBBB`. It seems removing `IAAA` from `MyClass` doesn't affect anything.

The reason why I'm asking this silly question is,
I see this kind of patterns quite often in **`Android` Open Source Project** and sometimes even in the standard `Java` `API` such as `ArrayList`.

One example I want to talk about is **`SpannableStringBuilder`**.

`Spanned` interface extends `CharSequence` interface.

`Spannable` interface extends `Spanned` interface.

`Editable` interface extends both `CharSequence` and `Spannable` interface.

`SpannableStringBuilder` class implements `CharSequence`, `Spannable`, `Editable` interface AGAIN.

I really don't get it. What's the point of doing this way? Why bother?

Comment: Android is a big team. I bet not everyone in android team do this. Not everyone in this team is an expert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no technical reason.  It may make it a bit easier in maintenance-  if Bar extends Foo and you want to find all the classes that implement Foo, you only have to look for Foo and not Foo and Bar.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation, reinforcing the fact that `MyClass` must implement `IAAA`, without forcing the (human) reader of the code to look at `IBBB` to know that.

Comment: Yeah, personally I almost always read API documentation but that's not everyone does and sometimes there's no reliable documentation so what you said makes sense.